# How to Select multiple columns Into a table PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a function with PL/SQL that return information about an employee, by getting the user input (code_Employe) and pass into this function.
So the function get this code or ID and search for the employee with this ID.

My problem is how that I don't know how to insert all the employee information in the return variable. Do I have to create a temporary table ?

Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fNombreProjets(code_Emp IN Employe.idEmploye%type) 
    RETURN varchar2
is
   info_Emp varchar2(200); 
BEGIN

    SELECT  e.IDEMPLOYE ,
            e.NOMEMPLOYE ,
            e.ADRESSE ,
            e.TELEPHONE ,
            e.ADRESSECOURRIEL
    INTO info_Emp
    FROM Employe e
    WHERE idEmploye= code_Emp;

    RETURN info_Emp;
EXCEPTION
       when no_data_found then
       return 'Aucun employe';
END;    
/

ACCEPT val NUMBER PROMPT 'Entrer le code Employé: '
DECLARE
    code_Emp   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    code_Emp := '&val';
    select fNombreProjets(code_Emp) result from dual;
END;
```

Comment: `infoEmp` is one string. What do you want to see in it after selecting 5 separate things?

Comment: i wanna display all informations about the employee depending on the id that user will input.
display: ID, Name of the employee, Adress, Phone, Email.

Comment: Why does it need to be a function and not a procedure?  A function is meant to return a single value, and can be used in a query ( as in SELECT MY_FUNCTION(input arguments) FROM MY_TABLE) or a value assignment ( as in MY_VAR := MY_FUNCTION(input arguments)   )  Think about how functions like TO_CHAR or SYSDATE work.

Answer (score 1):

A simple option, which requires just some minor changes to code you already wrote, is a function that returns ref cursor.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fNombreProjets(code_Emp IN Employe.idEmploye%type) 
    RETURN sys_refcursor
is
   info_Emp sys_refcursor; 
BEGIN
    OPEN info_Emp for
    SELECT  e.IDEMPLOYE ,
            e.NOMEMPLOYE ,
            e.ADRESSE ,
            e.TELEPHONE ,
            e.ADRESSECOURRIEL
    FROM Employe e
    WHERE idEmploye = code_Emp;

    RETURN info_Emp;
END;    
/
```

Call it then as

```
ACCEPT val NUMBER PROMPT 'Entrer le code Employé: '
SELECT fNombreProjets(&val) result FROM dual;
```

---

**[EDIT, to answer question you posted as a comment]**

Types first (I'll use Scott's `emp` sample table for this demo as I don't have your tables):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_emp_row AS OBJECT
  2  (
  3     empno NUMBER,
  4     ename VARCHAR2 (10),
  5     job VARCHAR2 (10),
  6     sal NUMBER
  7  );
  8  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t_emp_tab AS TABLE OF t_emp_row;
  2  /

Type created.
```

Function:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fNombreProjets (code_emp IN NUMBER)
  2     RETURN t_emp_tab
  3  IS
  4     retval  t_emp_tab;
  5  BEGIN
  6     SELECT t_emp_row (empno,
  7                       ename,
  8                       job,
  9                       sal)
 10       BULK COLLECT INTO retval
 11       FROM emp
 12      WHERE empno = code_emp;
 13
 14     RETURN retval;
 15  END;
 16  /

Function created.
```

Testing (employee that exists):

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE (fNombreProjets (7369));

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB               SAL
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK             920
```

Employee that doesn't exist:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM TABLE (fNombreProjets (-7369));

no rows selected

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that works perfectly, but is there any way to use exception (in the case if the employee does not exist) ?

Comment: Try to pass employee that does not exist. What happened? (...) Exactly, *nothing* happened, there was no error so - there's no need for an exception handler, not with ref cursor.

Comment: I am very beginner with pl/sql , and i never used the ref cursor before, i appreciate your help, but is there any other ways like creating a type object and return this object ?

Comment: (Sorry, I went to sleep) Yes, you can do that as well - have a look at edited answer, please.